# implementation of malloc and free

Tags: c

I have question with respect the `malloc` followed by `free`.

```
char *p = (char *) malloc(100);
p++;
free(p);
```

in the above scenario `free(p)` will free how many bytes of memory? Is it 99 or 100 ?

Comment: UB. And please drop the cast on the right hand side.

Answer (score 6):

This is undefined behavior. The manpage for `free()` says (emphasis mine):

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, **which
>   must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc() or
>   realloc(). Otherwise,** or if free(ptr) has already been called before,
>   **undefined behavior occurs.** If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed.

Comment: in other words, you have to return the same address (value of the pointer) to `free`.